# Why server changes single value on inserting?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query, executed from C# code to SQL Server 2008:

```
INSERT INTO [tableName] (valueColumn) @Value
```

Where `@Value` is name of the sql parameter with `DbType.Single` and `Value = 45.01`

After executing query I see in table value `45,0099983215332` instead of `45,01`

Why is it happening?

ps: column has type `float`

Comment: `float` is **NOT** an exact datatype - there will be rounding errors.... if you need more precise numbers, use `DECIMAL(p, s)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Everybody!
Changing sql-parameter type to SqlDBType.Float solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`valueColumn` is probably a floating point number.

> Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly.

Comment: when I write directly value in sql statement insted of using paramert, all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) link

Floating points can vary slightly from one architecture to another